# local extrema of a two variable function

Tags: function, equation-solving

I'm finding local extrema of functions right now and I have to admit I am stuck at one point for over one hour now and I cant see any way of doing it , perhaps wolfram alpha gives a real answer to this ,so I came to ask you guys for a helpful hand

f(x,y)=(x+y-1)^4

now everytinhg comes smoothly to the moment where I want to solve my system of equations for first degree partial derivatives

it looks like this:
4(x-y+1)^3=0
-4(x-y+1)^3=0

and now i dont know what to do
only thing that I can see is y=x+1 , but what about it because when i put this
for y in my equation its always 0=0